# Eclipse Neon Available Software list invisible

Tags: eclipse

When I open Help/Install New Software, then select a site under "Work with", e.g., http://www.baeyens.it/eclipse/V3, nothing shows up. However, if I click on Select All, it says "2 items selected", yet nothing is displayed.

Is this a problem with the font color? If so, where do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355955

See the comment about .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml